# Using JQuery to render a form on click of link Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am trying to get the Jquery to render a form on click of a link.

This is the link to click.

```
<%= link_to 'Try Link', new_user_path, :remote=>true, :class=>'create_user' %>
```

I have a class here which renders a form. I want to change it such that it would only show after the button is clicked.

```
<div class = "TestClass"><%= render 'form'%></div>
```

The javascript:
Right now I am able to change the text in the div class but I am not sure how I should go about putting the render form in the javascript.

```
$('.create_user').bind('ajax:success', function() { 
    //alert("Clicked");
    $(".TestClass").text("Ajax success");
});
```

I would appreciate it if someone could just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, make sure you render your view with no layout. Then you can easily do something like :

```
$('.create_user').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data) { 
    $(".TestClass").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help but I did it with a JQuery modal form instead.